# Register screen check if textboxes are empty

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

Hello guys i am trying to check if the input fields for my register screen are empty and give an error message for each one if any is empty.
I added the text editing controllers and the booleans for if each box is empty or not.
Then on button press it checks if there is no text in any of the fields and should display the error message for each of the field.
Right now it tells me that the text provided in this "errorText: _emptyboxmail ? 'field cannot be empty' : null," is dead code for each one.
If i change the boolean to true then it shows that null is dead code in code i gave above.
How do i make this work without having dead code? The program runs as usual it just not show me the error message if i leave the boxes empty

```
import 'package:club_mark_2/styles/style.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

import 'userPreferences/user_details_preference.dart';

class RegisterScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegisterScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RegisterScreenState createState() => _RegisterScreenState();
}

class _RegisterScreenState extends State<RegisterScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final registerEmail = TextEditingController();
    final registerPassword = TextEditingController();
    final verifyPassword = TextEditingController();
    final registerName = TextEditingController();
    bool _emptyboxmail = false;
    bool _emptyboxpass = false;
    bool _emptyboxverify = false;
    bool _emptyboxregistername = false;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    @override
    void dispose() {
      // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
      registerEmail.dispose();
      registerPassword.dispose();
      verifyPassword.dispose();
      registerName.dispose();
      super.dispose();
    }

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: SizedBox(
        width: width,
        height: height,
        child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
       
         
   
       
        
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 165, right: 15),
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'SIGN UP',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 30.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
    
            
          
                  
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      errorText: _emptyboxregistername
                          ? 'field cannot be empty'
                          : null,
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide:
                              BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5)),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                      hintText: 'Full Name',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: kcMediumGreyColor),
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      prefixIcon: const Icon(
                        Icons.person,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                    controller: registerName,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      errorText: _emptyboxmail ? 'field cannot be empty' : null,
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide:
                            BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5)),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      ),
                      hintText: 'E-mail',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: kcMediumGreyColor),
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      prefixIcon: const Icon(
                        Icons.email,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                    controller: registerEmail,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    obscureText: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      errorText: _emptyboxpass ? 'field cannot be empty' : null,
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide:
                            BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5)),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      ),
                      hintText: 'Password',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: kcMediumGreyColor),
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      prefixIcon: const Icon(
                        Icons.lock,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                    controller: registerPassword,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                ),
//VERIFY PASSWORD TEXT BOX
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    obscureText: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      errorText:
                          _emptyboxverify ? 'field cannot be empty' : null,
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide:
                            BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5)),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      ),
                      hintText: 'Verify Password',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: kcMediumGreyColor),
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      prefixIcon: const Icon(
                        Icons.lock,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
//TEXT EDITING CONTROLLER
                    controller: verifyPassword,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 60,
                  child: TextButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                        RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
// THE BUTTON THAT CHECKS IF THE BOOLEANS ARE TRUE OR FALSE FOR THE TEXT BEING EMPTY
                    onPressed: () {
                      registerEmail.text.isEmpty
                          ? _emptyboxmail = true
                          : _emptyboxmail = false;
                      registerName.text.isEmpty
                          ? _emptyboxregistername = true
                          : _emptyboxregistername = false;

                      registerPassword.text.isEmpty
                          ? _emptyboxpass = true
                          : _emptyboxpass = false;
                      verifyPassword.text.isEmpty
                          ? _emptyboxverify = true
                          : _emptyboxverify = false;
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => UserDetailsPreference(),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Text('Sign Up'),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "━━━━━  OR SIGN UP WITH  ━━━━━",
                        style: TextStyle(color: kcMediumGreyColor),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          child: Image.asset('lib/assets/images/googleIcon.png',
                              width: 50.0, height: 50.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 30,
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          child: Image.asset(
                              'lib/assets/images/facebookIcon.png',
                              width: 45.0,
                              height: 45.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "Already have an account?",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "SIGN IN",
                      style: TextStyle(color: kcPrimaryColor),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a Form with a GlobalKey
2. Add a TextFormField with validation logic
3. Create a button to validate and submit the form

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation

Answer (score 1):

You have to move all your initializations and `dispose` method out of build `method`.

```dart
class _RegisterScreenState extends State<RegisterScreen> {
  final registerEmail = TextEditingController();
  final registerPassword = TextEditingController();
  final verifyPassword = TextEditingController();
  final registerName = TextEditingController();
  bool _emptyboxmail = false;
  bool _emptyboxpass = false;
  bool _emptyboxverify = false;
  bool _emptyboxregistername = false;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    registerEmail.dispose();
    registerPassword.dispose();
    verifyPassword.dispose();
    registerName.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      body: SizedBox(
        width: width,
        height: height,

        // ... rest of your code
```

Comment: Amsakanna no longer showing dead code but the error messages are still not shown

Comment: if i set a boolean to true then the error message is showing but it is not being set to true by itself